# Swift Array Issues

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, struct, enums

I have this code:

```
let posState = positionState(pos)
if posState != .None {
    if posState == .Off {
        boardArray[pos.row][pos.column] == .On
    } else {
        boardArray[pos.row][pos.column] == .Off
    }
}
```

The issue I'm having is that when I attempt to change the value of an element in `boardArray`, nothing happens. Why does boardArray's element stay the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `==` rather than `=` for assigning

```
let posState = positionState(pos)
   if posState != .None {
      if posState == .Off {
         boardArray[pos.row][pos.column] = .On
      } else {
         boardArray[pos.row][pos.column] = .Off
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you. i must have been temporarily blind while I was banging my head against my desk lol. I'll mark this as the right answer in after stack overflow's time minimum has lapsed for marking an answer right.

Comment: Surprised that it compiles. I'd recommend turning all available warnings on.

Comment: Xcode actually doesn't show a warning for this at all :/

Answer (score 0):

Its not `==`, use the assignment operator `=`

```
   boardArray[pos.row][pos.column] = .On
```